# Is it correct to apply KVL across the input and the output circuits on an op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was watching a video that talks about the Driven right leg circuit. In that video, the guy stated two equations which I understood one of them but the second one, I couldn't figure out how did he came up with.

The first one was \$V_o=\frac{-R_f}{R_d}\cdot{V_{cm}}\$

This equation is pretty straightforward but the second one, **he literally just said** "Using KVL, we can say that \$V_{cm}=R_{rl}\cdot{I_d}+V_o\$"

How can we apply KVL in that sense?

\$I_d\$ is the drift current, \$V_{cm}\$ is the common-mode signal and \$R_{rl}\$ is the probe wire resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f41iVn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I suppose with "common-mode signal" you mean the DC portion of the sinusoidal input voltage, right? And what is Vo´´ ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an assumption that the 'load' is ground referenced. It's not drawn. i.e. the open end of Rrl is tied to something that's tied to ground.  Presumably Vo'' is the voltage on that load, right?   So there is a complete loop there, but you're supposed to connect the dots in your head apparently.

The gain of the opamp is unity (Rf=Rd), thus equation #1 reduces to Vcm=-Vo   The fact it's negative is irrelevant since this is an AC source.  i.e.  Vcm=Vo

Then your loop equation makes more sense if you sub Vo for Vcm

Answer (score 0):

The second equation seems to be used to imply that the following connection is made to complete the DRL circuit:

[image]

Comment: I do not think that such a connection (in red) makes sense.

Comment: @LvW Agreed. By saying "seems to be used to imply" I have not assumed correctness. I assumed Vo´´ == Vo, but lets wait for clarification following your comment. It is hard to analyze without the original reference and based on an incomplete/open circuit. Your approach (comment) is the correct one and I will wait some time for the improvement in the question.

Comment: Yes - it is not easy to answer a question without complete information about the circuit and the symbols used.